# Angular's reportProgress and PHP. One request, multiple responses. Is it possible?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have this php file that handles multiple requests on the backend upon submission of a form, and because it takes some time, I would like to inform the user of the progress, showing some notifications as the execution of the php proceeds and until the final response arrives. The messages sent from the php look like this:

```
$text = 'Getting time from server...';
$data = ['message' => $text];
echo json_encode($data);
...
...
...
$text = 'Server Time is ' . $syncTime;
$data = ['message' => $text];
echo json_encode($data);
```

This is the Http request that resides on a service:

```
 getResult(): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const url = `${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/getResult.php`;
        return this.http.get(url, {
            responseType: "json",
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: "events",
            headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
        });
    }
```

and on the component I subscribe to the above observable:

```
 onSubmit() {

        this.dbQuery
            .getResult()
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy))
            .subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
                    console.log("download progress", event);

                }
                if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
                    console.log("donwload completed", event);

                }
            });
    }
```

With this I can see several event objects on the console that look like this:

`Object { type: 3, loaded: 57 }
 Object { type: 3, loaded: 164 }`

but I don't get the actual messages sent from the php.

At the end the request returns an error with the message
`Http failure during parsing for http://127.0.0.1/backend/getResult.php`

Does anyone know what I should do to get the actual JSON response from the server?
Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting for a while, and making a few changes I was able to get the responses from the server by changing the `responseType` from `json` to `text`. I came up with the following.

On the server side, I added a separator between the messages, so now I have this

```
$text = 'Getting time from server...';
$data = ['message' => $text];
echo json_encode($data);
echo "|";
```

My request now looks like this:

```
getResult(): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const url = `${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/getResult.php`;
        return this.http.get(url, {
            responseType: "text",
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: "events",
            headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "text/plain" })
        });
    }
```

and this is how I manipulate the received data

```
onSubmit() {
        this.dbQuery
            .getResult()
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy))
            .subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {

                     //get the partialText property of the received event
                     const partialText = (<HttpDownloadProgressEvent>(event)).partialText;

                    //split the received text on '|' and filter empty elements 
                    let textArray: string[] = partialText.split("|").filter(x => x);

                    //array size
                    this.totalLength = textArray.length;

                    //take the last element of the string array
                    let responseTxt = textArray[this.totalLength - 1];

                    //convert it to an object
                    let res = JSON.parse(responseTxt);

                    console.log("response: ", res);

            });
    }
```

so now I have streaming responses from my backend.